# angular match value from passed array with item from loop on the page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

trying to match value from passed array and loop on the page

```
.then(function (data) {
    vm.outputL = data;
    vm.array = [];

    for(var i=0; i < vm.outputL.length; i++){

        vm.block = false;       
        if(vm.outputL[i].id < 100){

            vm.block = true;

        }

        vm.array.push(vm.block) 

    }
}
```

and html code

```
 <li ng-repeat="item in vm.outputL">
    <div>{[item.id]}</div>
    <div ng-if="vm.array">something</div>
 <li>
```

how can I match value from vm.block and loop item on the page?

Comment: what do you want to do exactly? also share more of your HTML code

Comment: @tanmay I would like to match value from vm.array with item in loop

Comment: So, you want to show something when it's id is less than 100. Is that right?

Comment: that was just a simple example I have more complex stuff, I just want to see how to match value from passed array and item within loop

Comment: @user1751287: Please check this fiddle. Is this something you require? http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/28608/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They way you handle data results `vm.array` and `vm.outputL` to have **different length**.

If I am not mistaken, what might be useful based on your question is to push `vm.block` without caring about its value so that you can **match** it to the itterating items.

This block might be useful:

Controller:

```
    vm.block = false;       
    if(vm.outputL[i].id < 100){
       vm.block = true;   
    }
    vm.array.push(vm.block)
```

Template:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in vm.outputL">
    <div>{[item.id]}</div>
    <div ng-if="vm.array[$index]">something</div>
 <li>
```

Comment: vm.array and vm.outputL actually have the same length, if you look at my code  vm.block = false  is also in a loop so both true and false will be in array hence the same length

Comment: You are pushing the `vm.block` only when `if` statement results `true` value.

Comment: then all you have to do is check the template block quote I've submitted

Comment: yeah I can immediately see that $index was missing, let me try it